# Unable to make network call from completion handler?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, ipad

I am trying to access the contacts of user form phone.So or that purpose i am using completion handler.So when app tries to access the contacts of user it shows an alert & asks for permission to allow the contacts.When user press the button 'OK'.

[image]

then a block is executed & that time i make network call.Although the function is called but the delegate is never called & response is never recieved.

```
ABAddressBookRef addressBookRef = ABAddressBookCreateWithOptions(NULL, NULL);
    if (ABAddressBookGetAuthorizationStatus() == kABAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined)
    {

        ABAddressBookRequestAccessWithCompletion(addressBookRef, ^(bool granted, CFErrorRef error) {
            // First time access has been granted, add the contact
            NSLog(@"access contact");
           [self sample];

        });
          NSLog(@"after sccess contact");

    }
    else if (ABAddressBookGetAuthorizationStatus() == kABAuthorizationStatusAuthorized)
    {
        // The user has previously given access, add the contact
        NSLog(@"previous access");
    }
    else
    {
        // The user has previously denied access
        // Send an alert telling user to change privacy setting in settings app
        NSLog(@"send alert");
    }
    CFErrorRef error = NULL;
```

**network call**

```
-(void)sample
{
    NSLog(@"sample func called");
    // Create the request.
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://google.com"]];

    // Specify that it will be a POST request
    request.HTTPMethod = @"POST";

    // This is how we set header fields
    [request setValue:@"application/xml; charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

    // Convert your data and set your request's HTTPBody property
    NSString *stringData = @"some data";
    NSData *requestBodyData = [stringData dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    request.HTTPBody = requestBodyData;

    // Create url connection and fire request
    sampleConn= [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
}
```

Comment: did you check failure delegate method?

Comment: Yes i have checked it.If i make network cal from [viewdidLoad] method then response is received.But in another case i don't recieve any response.@AshishP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Try this**

Replace your code

```
[self sample];
```

With

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

    [self sample];
});
```

Comment: Hey your previous answer worked in my demo code .@Ashish

Comment: I think as you were making ws call from completion block of address book reference, http request also taken delegate reference from completion block i.e actually delegate reference of address book. Hence finish method wont get called on your delegate.